# Как убрать символ новой строки (\n) при чтении строк из файла

Tags: python, файлы, python-3.x

При использовании file.readlines() получаем что-то вроде этого:

```
>>> file.readlines()
['12\n', '10\n', '9\n', '15\n', '10\n', '120']
```

Как убрать `\n`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> l = ['12\n', '10\n', '9\n', '15\n', '10\n', '120']
>>> l = [line.rstrip() for line in l]
>>> l
['12', '10', '9', '15', '10', '120']
```

Comment: стоит заметить, что `.rstrip()` также удаляет любой пробел в конце строки, а не только символы новой строки как `.rstrip('\n')` (это может и быть желаемым поведением).

Answer (score 6):

Если хочется поддерживать и Юникодные окончания строк, то [можно `str.splitlines()` метод использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> file.read().splitlines()
['12', '10', '9', '15', '10', '120']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
file = "file.txt"
open(file).read().split('\n')
```