# Строки в файле. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

```
with open (name + "_antvlog.txt", 'r') as file5:
   lines = file5.readlines()
       for line in lines:
          print (line)
```

Почему выводит с пробелом?

```
Title

String1

String2
```

Comment: потому что поcле readlines  в строках остаются переводы строки + плюс от print'

Comment: Используйте `print(line, end='')`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597892/Как-убрать-символ-новой-строки-n-при-чтении-строк-из-файла

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: безопаснее читать строки напрямую из `file5` - `for line in file5: ...` - так вы можете обрабатывать файлы, которые не помещаются в память